# How to resolve ImportError: no module named tarfile

Tags: python, jython

I am not able to use tarfile module in my python script.

When i run the script i am getting error "ImportError: no module named tarfile"

if i remove "import tarfile" then its failing at tarfile.open;
Error says--NameError: tarfile

```
def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    tar = tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")
    #tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
    tar.add(source_dir)
    tar.close()
```

The same thing happening for subprocess module also.
I have verified the modules and they exists. Note that all the modules are working in python console or at command line

Python Version#2.6

==code==

## !usr/bin/python

```
from java.io import FileInputStream
#import subprocess
import os
import time as systime
import datetime
import shutil
import sys
print  sys.path
import tarfile
import socket

def weblogicPassChange(dName,aUrl,aUser,aServerName,mServerName,aPort,oAdminPassword,nAdminPassword):
    print '############################################################'
    print '        Changing the admin password for :', dName
    print '############################################################'
    print ' '
    print '####'
    print 'dname : =',dName
    print 'aUrl  :=',aUrl
    print 'aUser :=',aUser
    print 'aServerName :=',aServerName
    print 'mServerName :=',mServerName
    print 'aPort  :=',aPort
    print 'oAdminPassword :=',oAdminPassword
    print 'nAdminPassword :=',nAdminPassword
    print '####'
   connect(aUser,oAdminPassword,aUrl+':'+aPort)
    cd('/SecurityConfiguration/'+dName+'/Realms/myrealm/AuthenticationProviders/DefaultAuthenticator')
    cmo.resetUserPassword(aUser,nAdminPassword)
    print '++++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++'
    print '*******  Congrates!!! ', dName , ' Admin Password Changed Successfully  ********'
    print '++++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++ +++++++++++'
    print ' '
    disconnect()
    print ' '
    print '####   Connecting Using New Credentials.....    ####'
    print ' '
    connect(aUser,nAdminPassword,aUrl+':'+aPort)
    print '####   Successfully Connected Using New Credentials !!!!    ####'
    print ' '
    domainRuntime()
    bean =getMBean('ServerRuntimes/' + mServerName)
    if bean:
       print ' '
       print 'Shutting down the Manage Server:  osb_server1'
       shutdown(mServerName,'Server')
    else:
       print ' '
       print 'Server ',mServerName,' is not running'
    print ' '
    disconnect()
    print ' '
    print '####   Changing Admin Password in boot.properties file   ####'
    print ' '
    text_file=open('/oraapp/config/domains/'+dName+'/servers/'+aServerName+'/security/boot.properties','w')
    text_file.write('#' + systime.strftime("%a")+' ' +systime.strftime("%b")+' '+systime.strftime("%d")+' '+systime.strftime("%H")+':'+systime.strftime("%M")+':'+systime.strftime("%S")+' '+systime.strftime("%Z")+' '+systime.strftime("%Y")+"\n")
    text_file.write("username" +"=" + aUser + "\n")
    text_file.write("password"+"=" + nAdminPassword)
    text_file.close()
    print ' '
    print '####  username and password updated in boot.properties   ####'
    print ' '
    shutil.copyfile('/oraapp/config/domains/'+dName+'/servers/'+aServerName+'/security/boot.properties','/oraapp/config/domains/'+dName+'/servers/'+mServerName+'/data/nodemanager/boot.properties')
    print ' '
    print 'Copied boot.properties to manage server location ManageServerHome/date/nodemanager'
    print ' '
    print '###  Calling stopWeblogic.sh file.....!!!!!! ######'
    print ' '
    os.system('.././config/domains/eapdomain/bin/stopWebLogic.sh')
    print ' '
    print 'Successfully changed weblogic password to',nAdminPassword
    print ' '
    print 'Test copy SCP function'
    print ' '
    string = 'scp /oraapp/config/domains/'+dName+'/servers/'+aServerName+'/security/test.properties'+' '+'s-fmwadmin@gaxgpoa163vd:/oraapp/config/domains/osbdomain1/servers/AdminServer/security'
    print 'string value is = ',string
    os.system('scp /oraapp/config/domains/'+dName+'/servers/'+aServerName+'/security/test.properties'+' '+'s-fmwadmin@gaxgpoa163vd:/oraapp/config/domains/osbdomain1/servers/AdminServer/security')
    print ' '
    print 'Copied successfully'


def envDetail(eName):
    propInputStream = FileInputStream(eName+'_'+'domainDetails.properties')
    configProps = Properties()
    configProps.load(propInputStream)
    domainName=configProps.get("domain.name")
    adminUrl = configProps.get("domain.admin.url")
    adminUser = configProps.get("domain.admin.username")
    adminPort = configProps.get("domain.admin.port")
    adminServerName = configProps.get("domain.adminServer.name")
    mgrServerName = configProps.get("domain.mgrServer.name")
    oldAdminPassword = configProps.get("domain.admin.OLD.password")
    newAdminPassword = configProps.get("domain.admin.NEW.password")
    fmw_home = configProps.get("domain.middlehome")              
    filename='/oraapp/backup/EAP_PRODUCT'+'_'+socket.gethostname()+'_'+systime.strftime("%d")+'-'+systime.strftime("%B")+'-'+systime.strftime("%Y")+'-'+systime.strftime("%T")+'.tar.gz'
    make_tarfile(filename,fmw_home)
    print 'Calling function weblogicPassChange()'
    print ' '
    weblogicPassChange(domainName,adminUrl,adminUser,adminServerName,mgrServerName,adminPort,oldAdminPassword,newAdminPassword)



def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    tar = tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz")
    #tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
    tar.add(source_dir)
    tar.close()

print '#########################################################################################'
print '        Enter the name of the environment as given below to change the password :'
print '#########################################################################################'
print 'For EAPDOMAIN enter  EAP'
print 'For SOCODEV/QA enter QA'
print 'For SOCOUA/UAT enter UAT'
print 'For PRODUCTION enter PROD'
print '############################################################'
print ' '
env = raw_input('Please enter your name: ')
 if env == 'EAP':
    print 'EAPDOMAIN'
    print env
    envDetail(env)
elif env == 'QA':
    print 'SOCODEV'
elif env == 'UAT':
    print 'SOCOUA'
elif env == 'PROD':
    print 'PRODUCTION'
print ' '
print 'Kindly Restart the Admin and Manager servers of ',env,' Domain'
```

Regards,
TJ

Comment: How do you invoke script? Can you add `print sys.path` right before failing import? (`import sys` before it, obviously)

Comment: Where is the `tarfile` module installed?  Are you sure it's installed for the same version of python that you're using?  What is your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @JohnGordon both `tarfile` and `subprocess` are built-ins.

Comment: Are you saying that you can access these modules in the Python prompt, but not in your scripts? That's curious

Comment: Are you sure you're running the correct interpreter version?

Comment: try `pip list` to ensure if you have the packages installed for your interpreter

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Ah, didn't realize `tarfile` was a standard module.  But still, printing `tarfile.__file__` might tell us something.

Comment: Are you running it from the command line or through an IDE? If the latter, have you properly configured the Python path in the IDE?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski the script invoke through shell script

Comment: @JohnGordon path to python /usr/lib/python2.6

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes i am able to access these module in the python prompt

Comment: @Bharel yes i am running with correct version

Comment: @Dan i am running in putty by opening python console.

Comment: All responses as text, no logs / dumps / code to look at. We won't be able to find an issue without it... My money is on `PYTHONPATH` environment variable being overwritten somewhere before starting interpreter.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski added print sys.path and before failing it printing all my the sys path  ['.', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar/Lib', '__classpath__', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/common/wlst', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/common/wlst/lib', '/oraapp/product/fmw/wlserver/common/wlst/modules']

Comment: @user1760923 well, it's definitely does not look like any standard PYHONPATH...

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski well when i run python on my putty it instantly so it should be a problem connected to python console s-fmwadmin@xxxxxvd:/usr/lib/python2.6$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski i have added the code , sorry i am not perfect in formatting

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski if its overwritten environment variable then the script shouldn't work , but if i comment the tarfile part then he script works perfectly without any issue

Comment: @user1760923 ok, maybe your Python installation is broken? `PYTHONPATH` is highly unusual, almost look like you're running Jython and not Python, but headers do no match. I can't help, I'm really not familiar with whole your setup.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Thanks for your time.

Comment: If your `sys.path` dump has .jar files, that implies that what's actually at use in the runtime environment at hand isn't CPython but is Jython; that's a **critical** detail (and it explains why you wouldn't have the same issue running invoking `python` from your OS).

Comment: This is Jython....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need 50 reputation to comment, so I'll leave an answer instead:

Could you add the following line to your script:

```
print sys.version
```

Just to make absolutely sure the Python version running the script is the same as the one you use as an interpreter. Like people said, maybe an environment variable is overwritten somewhere, causing a wrong version of Python to run the script.

Comment: I think your right , when i give print sys.version its print 2.2.1. How to resolve this? I am using wlst interaction to call the script.This code prints the jython version use, which is equal to the Phyton version on which jython is based.On WebLogic 12c the jython/python version is 2.2.1.Could you pls let me know how to overriddle the version or how to run tar command in 2.2.1 version

Comment: I have no knowledge about WLST, but according to [their docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/wlst_faq.htm#WLSTG243) they use a pinned version of Jython.

I Googled for a standalone tar library, but without success. What you could do is make an OS call to to run the `tar` utility to do what you want. Perhaps that's an option?